# ReactJS react-bootstrap From.Control date picker format

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datepicker, react-bootstrap

I have been trying to make a page with ReactJS. I use Bootstrap for this and I am making a sign-up form, in which I use the react-bootstrap component for forms, `<Form>`. I also have a date picker for the birthday and it uses `<Form.Control>`, but the web page is in another language and as such I want to change the date format and language of the calendar. I have tried to replace it with a normal input jsx component and manually assign the className property and then using JQuery to change the format, but that didn't work. In JQuery I got datepicker is not a function, even if both 'jquery' and 'jquery-ui' were installed to the project and imported in the container. How can I do this?